# What are some effective approaches to enhancing fossils in amateur found rocks?

Tags: geology, fossils

My stepson found this rock on the shore of Lake Michigan and gave it to my son who loves fossils.

[image: front side]

[image: back side]

I'd like to really bring out those fossils.

What are some techniques that I can try that won't destroy the fossils and may expose other things under the white stone on the front side?

Comment: what you have found there might not be fossils at all,many aquatic animals leave this type of marks on the surface of rocks.it is a bit hard to tell if this is a sedmentary rock from your pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is a dental pick and time, maybe a little superglue. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLAGC3QpINI) is a video on using this method, its time consuming but you are less likely to destroy anything. there are faster method but without training they are also likely to destroy the fossils especially with smaller fossils.

Alternatively you can try polishing which may work, without knowing the type of rock matric it can be hard to tell. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2LYE_RzxRZWNmddKFWV6Kw) is a series of video on polishing and preparing private fossils. just don't try any of his more aggressive methods on something so small.